# Can I access a sequelize model directly in a nestjs controller?

Tags: sequelize.js, nestjs, sequelize-typescript

The [docs have](https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/database#sequelize-integration) it going through a service, but that feels unnecessary for my application. Can I somehow just access the models directly with `nestjs`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, `@InjectModel()` injects a provider, similar to `FeatureService` so you can do everything in the controller if you want. Just change `FeatureService` to `@InjectModel(FeatureModel) featureModel: Model<Feature>` and it should work out just fine.

Comment: In the `constructor` of the controller?

Comment: Yep. Just as you normally would `constructor(@InjectModel(FeatureModel) private readonly featureModel: Model<Feature>) {}`

Comment: In the `feature.module`, do I add my model as an `import` or `provider`?

Comment: Add it as an import as your normally would. `SequelizeModule.forFeature([Feature])`

Comment: This is the exact same as any other setup, you're just cutting out the use of the service class